# LineCount program in java. ignoring some lines in counting

Tags: java, line-count

I have a program in Java with the following code:

```
import java.io.*;
public class LineCountingProg
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      FileInputStream fis = null;
      try
      {
         fis = new FileInputStream("d://MyFile.txt");
      }
      catch(FileNotFoundException e)
      {
         System.out.println("The source file does not exist. " +e );
      }          
      LineNumberReader lineCounter = new LineNumberReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
      String nextLine = null;
      try {
      while ((nextLine = lineCounter.readLine()) != null) {
  System.out.println(nextLine);
  if ((nextLine.startsWith("/*") && nextLine.endsWith("*/"))
            || (nextLine.trim().matches("[{};]+"))) {
          //This line needs to be ignored
          ignoredLines++;
          continue;
                    }
        }
  System.out.println("Total number of line in this file " + lineCounter.getLineNumber());
  int fcounter  = 0;
  fcounter = lineCounter.getLineNumber()-ignoredLines ;
  System.out.println("Total " +fcounter);
  } catch (Exception done) {
  done.printStackTrace();

  }}}
```

I want to add a piece of code so it could ignore line counts if a line starts with /* and ends with */. Also if a line contains only ; and } it should be also ignore those lines. How can I do that?

Comment: Look at using String methods to see what the line begins and ends with. The String API will list the methods available, and the method names will be self-explanatory for your purposes. In other words, if you look you will find the important methods quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outside your while loop, you need to first create a variable to count all ignored lines.

```
int ignoredLines = 0;
```

Inside your while loop, you can add the following condition:

```
if ((nextLine.startsWith("/*") && nextLine.endsWith("*/"))
    || (nextLine.trim().matches("[};]+"))) {
  //This line needs to be ignored
  ignoredLines++';
  continue;
}
```

Finally:

```
System.out.println("Total number of line in this file " + lineCounter.getLineNumber() - ignoredLines);
```

`startsWith`, `endsWith` and `equals` are found in the `String` class.

Comment: "If a line contains *only*", should be translated to `equals` instead of `contains`

Comment: This doesn't solve the OP's question. He wants to exclude strings that contain ONLY ; and }, not any strings that contain those characters.

@dan your solution doesn't work either since a line could contain multiple ; or } or some combination of the two

Comment: @drewhannay You are rigth :). He can replace the two `equals` with: `nextLine.trim().matches("[};]+")` for that.

Comment: @dan, I'm using your solution. I just realised my mistake.

Comment: Thanks dear ... The Elite Gentlemnt. for your help

Comment: I am still confused. I dont know where do add the pieace of code.Please help me as I am new to java.

Comment: If you read my answer, I stated, inside your while loop `while ((nextLine = lineCounter.readLine()) != null)`.

Comment: Dear " The Elite Gentleman ". You are really a gentleman. I have added it but it is not functionning.

Comment: I suggest updating your question with the full code so that we can figure out what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Dear "The Elite Gentleman"
I have edited the code. Kindly check it. Always appreciate you.

Comment: Thank you so much dear "The Elite Gentleman" You are Genious. I have checked the output. It works for ignoring } and ;. But still there is issue with comments like ignoring /* and */ lines. It is still counting as a LOC. Thanks once again for ur support. Also I have updated the code you can check it.

Comment: This is going out of hand. I can't help without data. Also, I would suggest `trim()` your `String` before processing it.

Comment: You have done enough dear. The Elite Gentleman. I will try. Thanks for you support.